# Редактирование файла Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пытаюсь внести изменения в класс, а мне пишет "Только для чтения". Как исправить?

Comment: Дополните вопрос. Добавьте ОС, путь и права доступа к файлу. Если права есть, тогда вопрос оставим ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта проблема может решиться таким способом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же можете перейти в проводник, найти файл который собираетесь отредактировать и перейти в его свойства. Там можно настроить права доступа к данному файлу. Еще один [способ](https://android.okhelp.cz/android-studio-lock-unlock-file-make-read-only-or-writable/): `Files> Made File Writable`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самый последний вариант - создать новый проект (по возможности) и перенести код туда, на случай если совсем ничего не получится.